# Axis2 PhaseException ServiceClient.engageModule()

Tags: java, apache-axis

Hi i am facing an issue with modules in Axis2 1.6.2.
As per the axis documentation, I have created a module.xml, also i have updated the phase in axis2.xml.

Now when i try to engage a module using

`ServiceClient.enageModule()`.

I get a PhaseException as follows

```
org.apache.axis2.phaseresolver.PhaseException: Did not find the desired phase 'myPhase' while deploying handler 'MyInFlowHandler'.
```

I think the configuration (xml) is just fine as needed...i even tried keeping the`.mar` file in `lib` folder and included in the build path.

I have searched and all point to something missing in xml `axis2.xml or services.xml or module.xml` may cause this exception, i have checked and all the files are fine.

Also when i do this:

`Map<String, AxisModule> modules = serviceClient.getAxisConfiguration().getModules();`

the map(modules) is not empty and contains my module that needs to be engaged.

Other thing that i should mention is that i am creating a new MessageContext and somehow m MessageContext.getCurrentMessageContext() returns null.

I want to find out if the improper xml declaration is the only reason for this PhaseException or is there any other reason to it that I may be neglecting.

I hope i was clear as i am sorry cannot provide any more details(code and all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved...
Apparently the issue was no ServiceContext/ ConfigurationContext was found for the ServiceClient to load all the modules(mar's).

Creating a ServiceClient with a new custom ConfigurationContext did the trick.

```
ConfigurationContext CTX = new ConfigurationContext("path to axis2 repo","path to axis2.XML");

ServiceClient sender=new ServiceClient(CTX, null);
```